# processing a list gives the error "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"

Tags: python, list, tuples

This code is meant to take a string as input, and then produce a 2d array of the frequency of letter appearing after each other. So for each iteration, it increases the value of the integer in the array (for example `HI` would be `[h][i] =+ 1`).

My issue is the error message

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

coming up whenever I run the below code. I have changed the way the array is created so it is now created as a list, which is confirmed when I enter debugging mode (letterArray becomes a list of lists.)

The reason i convert the letter to ASCII is so that I can compare it to other ASCII values to clean the string at the same time. I intend to convert the string to lower case later.

I have tried converting letterArray into a list, although this does not change anything as letterArray is a list. I cannot find any relavent infromation on a 2d array with the same issue.

```
inputString = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat'  #just a test string
inputStringArray = list(inputString)        #break into char arrray
letterArray = []
posY = 28
x=0

for i in range(26):             #create balnk list of 0s of size 26x26
    letterArray.append([])
    for j in range(26):
        letterArray[i].append(0)

for letter in inputStringArray:
    posX = ord(letter)-97                   #-97 so that a = 0, z = 25
    if posY is 28 and posX <= 26 and posX >= 0:                     #instantiate first instance of past letter
        posY = posX
        continue
    if posX <= 26 and posX >= 0:                #if the char is a letter
        x = letterArray[posY,posX]
        x +=1
        letterArray[posY,posX] = x             #increment the space in the array by 1
        posY = posX
    else:
        continue
```

The exact error is:

```
Message=list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
  Source=C:\Users\me\source\repos\InputRecorder\InputRecorder\Recording.py
StackTrace:
  File "C:\Users\me\source\repos\InputRecorder\InputRecorder\Recording.py", line 103, in KeysToArray
    x = letterArray[posY,posX]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can not index list using `letterArray[posY,posX]` to access a nested list use `letterArray[posY][posX]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made the nested list which you can access by below syntax:

```
x = letterArray[posY][posX]
```

Comment: It make no sense to slice list from some Y position to some X position, they should point to one specific value.

Comment: Oh my I am a dummy. Thanks Amit. 
Filip, what do you mean? Are you referring to the unnecessary part of extracting the value, editing it, and then posting it back in?

Comment: @P.B I added an answer with a few suggestions to improve your code

Answer (score 0):

I see there is an answer that solves your error message, but I want to give a few suggestions to improve your code.

Here `f1()` is your code and `f2()` is my improved suggestion; it has less code, is more understandable in my opinion and takes a lot less time to run.

```
def f1(inputString):
    inputStringArray = list(inputString)            # break into char arrray
    letterArray = []
    posY = 28

    for i in range(26):                             # create balnk list of 0s of size 26x26
        letterArray.append([])
        for j in range(26):
            letterArray[i].append(0)

    for letter in inputStringArray:
        posX = ord(letter)-97                       # -97 so that a = 0, z = 25
        if posY is 28 and posX <= 26 and posX >= 0: # instantiate first instance of past letter
            posY = posX
            continue

        if posX <= 26 and posX >= 0:                # if the char is a letter
            x = letterArray[posY][posX]
            x +=1
            letterArray[posY][posX] = x             # increment the space in the array by 1
            posY = posX
        else:
            continue

    return letterArray

def f2(input_str):
    max_n = 26

    # build nested lists with zeros
    letter_list = [
        [0, ] * max_n
        for _ in range(max_n)]

    # 'None' is usually used to indicate an invalid value
    prev_i = None

    for letter in input_str:
        curr_i = ord(letter) - 97

        if 0 <= curr_i <= max_n:
            if prev_i is not None:
                letter_list[prev_i][curr_i] += 1

            prev_i = curr_i

    return letter_list
```

Asserting that the results are the same:

```
>>> s = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat'
>>> r1 = f1(s)
>>> r2 = f2(s)
>>> r1 == r2
True
```

Comparing runtimes (`f2` takes half the time of `f1` for this sample input):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('f1(s)', 'from __main__ import f1, s', number=10000)
1.0122240540222265
>>> timeit.timeit('f2(s)', 'from __main__ import f2, s', number=10000)
0.4270052219508216
```